# Multiple encoding types for Alamofire Request

Tags: alamofire

I need to make a `POST` request with an HTTP Body with a `JSON` object, but I also need to use url query parameters in the same request.

```
POST: http://www.example.com/api/create?param1=value&param2=value
HTTP Body: { foo : [ bar, foo], bar: foo}
```

Is this supported by Alamofire? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely a valid use case. I've ran into similar issues with trying to append access tokens as query parameters to a POST request. Here's a function that should make things a bit easier for the time being that is similar to your approach.

```
func multiEncodedURLRequest(
    method: Alamofire.Method,
    URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    URLParameters: [String: AnyObject],
    bodyParameters: [String: AnyObject]) -> NSURLRequest
{
    let tempURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString.URLString)!)
    let URLRequest = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(tempURLRequest, parameters: URLParameters)
    let bodyRequest = ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(tempURLRequest, parameters: bodyParameters)

    let compositeRequest = URLRequest.0.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
    compositeRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
    compositeRequest.HTTPBody = bodyRequest.0.HTTPBody

    return compositeRequest
}
```

With that said, could you make sure to put in a feature request issue on the [Github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues)? This is certainly something we need to figure out how to make easier in Alamofire since it's such a common use case. If you could put in a really good description of your use case, then I'm sure it will get attention. I will certainly help press to get support added.

Comment: This is similar to the way I'm doing it below. Thanks @cnoon! I've already put in an issue on Alamofire and @mattt has stated that he is not planning on supporting this, and that the way we are doing this is the correct way to make this happen.

Comment: Hey dude, could you hit me up with the issue # on the Alamofire Github project so I can take a look?

Comment: why Use of undeclared type 'URLStringConvertible' ?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I've decided to solve this by manually encoding an `NSURLRequest` with the URL parameters, retrieving the URL from that request, and using that to create the final request. I've created a function to return the query parameter encoded request:

```
private func queryParameterEncodedRequestURL(urlString: String,
values: [String]) -> NSURL {

  let URL = NSURL(string: urlString)
  var request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)

  let parameters = [
  "param1": values[0]!,
  "param2": values[1]!
  ]

  let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
  (request, _) = encoding.encode(request, parameters: parameters)

  return (request.URL, nil)
}
```

This works fine, but I would definitely like to see Alamofire support multiple encoding types more easily. This feels like a workaround to me.